Unable to listen to WinApi messages using JNA on Kotlin Multiplatform App
Im trying to set messaging between two instances of my kotlin desktop (windows) project.
The app is a music player and the idea is that once an instance of the app is already running, new instances will message that instance with file to play instead of opening new instances, then close them.
I tried using a local file to read and write but its not reliable enough, so now im trying to use JNA to send and receive messages between the two instances.
this is my function to listen and receive messages:
private fun setupMessagesListener(){
    val user32 = User32.INSTANCE
    val messagePump = Thread {
        val msg = MSG()
        val window = user32.FindWindow(null, "MyAppName")

        while (user32.GetMessage(msg, window, 0, 0) > 0){
            if (msg.message == WinUser.WM_COPYDATA){
                val copyData = COPYDATASTRUCT(msg.pointer)
                val chars = copyData.lpData.getCharArray(0, copyData.cbData / 2)
                val filePath = String(chars)
                val file = File(filePath)
                if (file.exists()){
                    handleFileArgument(filePath)
                }
            }
        }
        user32.TranslateMessage(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessage(msg)

    }
    messagePump.start()
}

and this is the function to send messages:
private fun sendFilePathMessage(filePath: String){

    val user32 = User32.INSTANCE
    val activeInstance = user32.FindWindow(null, "MyAppName")

    activeInstance?.let {
        val wideString = filePath.toCharArray()
        val size = (wideString.size * Char.SIZE_BYTES) + Char.SIZE_BYTES
        val buffer = Memory(size.toLong())
        buffer.setWideString(0, filePath)

        val copyData = COPYDATASTRUCT().apply {
            dwData = ULONG_PTR(0)
            cbData = size
            lpData = buffer
        }
        val pointer = copyData.pointer
        copyData.write()

        user32.SendMessage(activeInstance, WinUser.WM_COPYDATA, null, WinDef.LPARAM(Pointer.nativeValue(pointer)))
    }
}

when i debug my listener function, it always stop at while condition and never gets inside the loop, nor it comes back.
when i try to evaluate
user32.GetMessage(msg, window, 0, 0)

the debugger never finishes its just stuck.

GetMessage() retrieves posted messages for the calling thread only. The hWnd parameter can be used to filter messages. It doesn't magically have messages for a different thread show up in your thread.

@IInspectable in that case, how can i receive a message from the other instance?

Have the message loop run on the same thread that owns the window (and remove the message filter).

@IInspectable i dont really understand how to implement that, since if i'm not putting the message loop inside a Thread { }, it will freeze the main thread, which causes the ui to get stuck. any resources i can dig through?
